# What should I change in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have website: 
http://marekzurek.com

I'd like to change menu font size to 14px and make social media icons 200% bigger.

My CSS: https://past ebin.com/EuAw67mf

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of your markup that shows the problem here, not your web site which will change tomorrow helping no one in the future.

Answer (score 0):

1. `#menuid-or-class { font-size:14px;}`
2. `.icon-class {font-size:200%;}`

Answer (score 0):

first for the font size go to your css on line 352 and change font-size: 10px; to 14px. Then for the icons go on line 844 and up the font size.

Comment: On line 844 I see: 

.header-links ul li a {
    color: #fafafa;
}

Answer (score 0):

Simply set `font-size` to the right value for both the menu and icons.

In your `style.css` find `.mainmenu .navbar-nav li a` and add `font-size: 14px;`

```css
.mainmenu .navbar-nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

As for the icons, do the same and set `font-size` to `200%;`

```css
.social-links ul li a {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #222222;
    margin: 25px 10px;
    display: block;
}
```